# Trying to achieve this styling for messages

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement this design into the website I'm working on and i seem to be having some trouble. How do i accomplish this kind of styling.

http://i255.photobucket.com/albums/hh140/testament1234/message_zps7c5582b0.jpg

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span12">
    <div id="message-container">
      <div class="message">
        <img src="images/message_avatar.jpg" alt="Profile Avatar" />
        <h2>Charles Geschke</h2>
        <h3 class="time">10:00 A.M</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc condimentum a nunc sit amet bibendum. Vivamus vel eros at turpis volutpat euismod quis eget dui. Nunc a ultrices lacus, eget porta ipsum. Phasellus vel ornare urna. Cras accumsan ipsum a dui vestibulum mattis. Aenean a arcu porttitor quam molestie auctor.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.message{background-color:#eeeeee; padding:10px}
.message h2{margin-bottom:10px}
.message img{float:left; margin-right:10px;}
```

This is my coded that i have tried but it's not working properly since the image is floated and the text is going underneath

### [CodePen](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/KtuBF)

Comment: Those folks cheat - [it's an image](http://i255.photobucket.com/albums/hh140/testament1234/message_zps7c5582b0.jpg).

Comment: make h2,h3 and p inside another div and try adding 'float:left' to tha div with a fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span12">
    <div id="message-container">
      <div class="message">
        <img src="images/message_avatar.jpg" alt="Profile Avatar" />
        <div class="entry-content">
        <h2>Charles Geschke</h2>
        <h3 class="time">10:00 A.M</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc condimentum a nunc sit amet bibendum. Vivamus vel eros at turpis volutpat euismod quis eget dui. Nunc a ultrices lacus, eget porta ipsum. Phasellus vel ornare urna. Cras accumsan ipsum a dui vestibulum mattis. Aenean a arcu porttitor quam molestie auctor.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.message img,
.message .entry-content{
    display:inline-block; 
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `padding-left` to all of the text elements (I'd recommend a fixed width for the image as well). You can lose the `margin-right` and just compensate in the padding.

```
.message img{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
}
.message p,
.message h2,
.message h3{
        padding-left:110px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/R7zaq/

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap individual the content from image.

1) Wrap the contents using `wrap` as id.

2) Wrap the heading (`h2` and `h3`) using `wrapHeader` as id.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="message">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="Profile Avatar" />
    <div id="wrap">  <!-- Wrap the conents-->
        <div id='wrapHeader'>
             <h2>Charles Geschke</h2>
             <h3 class="time">10:00 A.M</h3>
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc condimentum a nunc sit amet bibendum. Vivamus vel eros at turpis volutpat euismod quis eget dui. Nunc a ultrices lacus, eget porta ipsum. Phasellus vel ornare urna. Cras accumsan ipsum a dui vestibulum mattis. Aenean a arcu porttitor quam molestie auctor.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrap {
    margin-left: 115px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
#wrapHeader h2, h3 {
    display: inline-block;
}
#wrapHeader h3 {
    float: right
}
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MykpK/)